# Apache Beam: why is the timestamp of aggregate value in Global Window 9223371950454775?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We migrated from Google Dataflow 1.9 to Apache Beam 0.6. We are noticing a change in the behavior to the timestamps after applying the globalwindow. In Google Dataflow 1.9, we would get the correct timestamps in the DoFn after windowing/combine function. Now we get some huge value for the timestamp e.g. 9223371950454775, Did the default behavior for the globalwindow change in Apache Beam version?

```
input.apply(name(id, "Assign To Shard"), ParDo.of(new AssignToTest()))
      .apply(name(id, "Window"), Window
          .<KV<Long, ObjectNode >>into(new GlobalWindows())
          .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(
              AfterProcessingTime
                  .pastFirstElementInPane()
                  .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(1))))
          .discardingFiredPanes())
      .apply(name(id, "Group By Shard"), GroupByKey.create())
      .appy(.....) }
```

Comment: I would highly recommend going directly to Beam 2.0.0 since that is the point where we guarantee some API compatibility for the future. We also addressed a lot of issues leading up to the 2.0.0 release.

Comment: We will upgrade to 2.0.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: When you are combining a bunch of timestamped values, you need to choose a timestamp for the result of the aggregation. There are multiple good answers for this output timestamp. In Dataflow 1.x the default was the minimum of the input timestamps. Based on our experience with 1.x in Beam the default was changed to the end of the window. You can restore the prior behavior by adding `.withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.EARLIEST)` to your `Window` transform.

---

I'll unpack this. Let's use the @ sign to pair up a value and its timestamp. Focusing on just one key, you have timestamped values *v1@t1*, *v2@t2*, ..., etc. I will stick with your example of a raw `GroupByKey` even though this also applies to other ways of combining the values. So the output iterable of values is  *[v1, v2, ...]* in arbitrary order.

Here are some possibilities for the timestamp:

- *min(t1, t2, ...)*
- *max(t1, t2, ...)*
- the end of the window these elements are in (ignoring input timestamps)

All of these are correct. These are all available as options for your `OutputTimeFn` in Dataflow 1.x and `TimestampCombiner` in Apache Beam.

The timestamps have different interpretations and they are useful for different things. The output time of the aggregated value governs the downstream watermark. So choosing earlier timestamps holds the downstream watermark more, while later timestamps allows it to move ahead.

- *min(t1, t2, ...)* allows you to unpack the iterable and re-output *v1@t1*
- *max(t1, t2, ...)* accurately models the logical time that the aggregated value was fully available. Max does tend to be the most expensive, for reasons to do with implementation details.
- end of the window:

  - models the fact that this aggregation represents *all* the data for the window
  - is very easy to understand
  - allows downstream watermarks to advance as fast as possible
  - is extremely efficient

For all of these reasons, we switched the default from the *min* to end of window.

In Beam, you can restore the prior behavior by adding `.withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.EARLIEST)` to your `Window` transform. In Dataflow 1.x you can migrate to Beam's defaults by adding `.withOutputTimeFn(OutputTimeFns.outputAtEndOfWindow())`.

Another technicality is that the user-defined `OutputTimeFn` is removed and replaced by the `TimestampCombiner` enum, so there are only these three choices, not a whole API to write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it makes a lot of sense. I will be great to have this documented in the javadoc.

Comment: Hello - I was reading through the "Watermark Propagation" chapter in the book and on page 76, in the footnote it mentioned that the "start of the window is not a safe choice". I didn't quite follow why. Isn't the "start of the window" a special case of "min(t1, t2...)" mentioned above - with the effect of delaying the watermark even more.

Comment: I don't know the context of the remark in the book. You are correct that it is a special case of taking the minimum. In fact many use cases _require_ that you take the minimum.