# Apache Beam - Wrong timestamp after window aggregation

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a pipeline where I want to calculate an accumulated sum. This is the code

```
input
    .apply(WithTimestamps.<Row>of(row -> Instant.ofEpochMilli(row.getInt64("my_timestamp"))))
    .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(), TypeDescriptors.longs()))
            .via((Row row) -> KV.of(row.getString("key"), row.getInt64("val"))))
    .apply(Window.<KV<String, Long>>into(new GlobalWindows())
            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
            .accumulatingFiredPanes()
            .withTimestampCombiner(TimestampCombiner.LATEST))
    .apply(Combine.<String, Long, Long>perKey(Sum.longsGlobally().getFn()));
```

The KV elements each represent a `Long` count and a `String` group for a specific day. For each group and day, there is only one KV entry. Each entry has a timestamp with the correct day. When I output the timestamps for each entry before the `Combine` step, the timestamps are ok. But after the `Combine` step, the timestamps for every item are `9223371950454775`.

I know this has to do with assigning the timestamps after the windowing process. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45286321/3272409) question, which seems to have the same problem. But the solution doesn't work. For every `TimestampCombiner` (`EARLIEST`, `LATEST` and `END_OF_WINDOW`) I get the same timestamp `9223371950454775`.

Comment: TimestampCombiner is the right answer here. What runner are you using?  Do you get the wrong timestamps when using the DirectRunner?

Comment: I haven't specified the runner explicitly but the pipeline is running on my local machine so I guess I am already using the DirectRunner. The timestamps are added to the rows using the WithTimestamp transform.

Comment: Can you expand your question to include how you are setting and checking thetimestamps?

Comment: Sure I've updated my question.